# Why do some websites keep on rendering local fonts?

Tags: fonts, website

Just for example. Look at Docker's website.
[image: Docker]

I found out that it is rendering local font, but I don't know why and how...
[image: Local font]

Disabling local font and reloading works fine, but it returns to its original form as soon as I exit Dev Options.
PS: This is the same for all of my browsers on a device but is working on other devices. So, is it a problem because of the extra font I have downloaded on this device? But I tried removing it too. All I am looking for is a permanent solution for this.

#### EDITED:

Unchecking this too works.
[image: Font]

**Does that mean I need to install this font or else the page will use random font on my PC?**

#### Checked

[image: Checked]

#### Unchecked

[image: Unchecked]

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Currently using brave but it's same for chrome and edge too on this device.

Comment: what does it look like with local fonts disabled? Can you check the console to see if any fonts 404 on loading, and check what the font is specified in the CSS of the site?

Comment: Edited about font...

Comment: do you see how that line is crossed out? that means the browser is ignoring it. What is it getting overridden by? Did you set your browser to default to this font?

Comment: **"do you see how that line is crossed out?"** --Yep I manually unchecked it.

Comment: is the font you installed called "Poppins" by any chance? If it is, it's the font the website intended to use.

Comment: Nope, I don't have a font called **Poppins**.

Comment: what font did you install? can you show an image of what it looks like when you uncheck the box? To confirm: is this Windows or some other OS?

Comment: ok, apparently the "poppins" font Docker uses includes devanagari script, and somehow your browser is using the devanagari font you installed when "poppins" is requested, even though the language is English, is that right? What font did you install, and how? It seems that somehow your browser thinks it's "poppins", I'm still trying to figure out why

Answer (score 1):

The way website fonts work is that they list a bunch of fonts one after another, and the browser will look to see if your computer has that font installed. If it does, the font is used; if it doesn't, the browser moves on to the next font in the list, eventually arriving at a generic font that it defaults to if it can't find the more specific ones.

For example,

```
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

in a website would look if you have Arial installed and use that, or if not try Helvetica, or finally, if you have neither of those, use whatever sans-serif font is default on your computer.

Websites can also use internet fonts, which allows them to load in fonts over the internet that aren't present on your device. If the font it chose, however unusual, *is* present on your device, it will load the font from your device rather than trying to download it on the spot, which saves in loading times. If, for whatever reason, the internet fonts don't load, the site will default to installed fonts.

The "disable local fonts" option is present for web developers, so that they can test that internet fonts do, in fact, load properly, even when the dev has the font installed on their machine (and the site would otherwise pull the font from their machine instead of loading it over the internet). That's why it's in dev tools, and why it only is enabled *while you have dev tools open*.

So in short, you can't force the browser not to use installed fonts: that's intended behavior if it has no other fonts. If you're seeing an installed font, one of a few things may be happening:

1. The site chose that particular font as its first-priority font.
2. Internet fonts didn't load, and it defaulted to this font
3. Some very strange bug is happening

You can troubleshoot this by opening dev tools and checking the console for any errors with regard to loading fonts, and also check the font that is specified in the CSS to see if it's using the correct font.

Comment: No, I don't see any error regarding font. **Internet fonts didn't load, and it defaulted to this font**-But why would this happen? I have seen this for more than a year or so. I have a edit in the question can you check that too...